# Lowest Common Ancestor Of Binary Tree Iteratively

Tags: python-3.x, iteration, binary-tree, lowest-common-ancestor

How to find Lowest Common Ancestor of Binary Tree without using recursion?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27590257/least-common-ancestor-search-in-binary-tree-non-recursive-version-java

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to find the lowest common ancestor of two nodes in any binary tree?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1484473/how-to-find-the-lowest-common-ancestor-of-two-nodes-in-any-binary-tree)